# Can you create a JWT token for AppStoreConnect API using Paw?

Tags: paw-app

I'm just starting to look at the AppStoreConnect API, and thought PAW would be rather useful in figuring out the various calls that can be made and the data returned.

I do have ruby code to generate the signed JWT token, but I was wondering if it is possible to generate this signed JWT token from within PAW itself

Is this possible, and if so, could someone advise me on what I need to do? Thank you!

Comment: https://paw.cloud/extensions/JsonWebTokenDynamicValue

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that out